# Python Framework for Desktop Database Application

Tags: python, database, frameworks, desktop

Is there a framework to develop Desktop Database applications (some screens with CRUD screens) for Python? I am looking for something similar to Windows Forms, with the ability to associate TextField, Combos and other UI metaphors with *datasets* connected to relational *databases* such as MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle or PostgreSQL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQT should be able to do that, altough I never used it myself ([See this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30649&seqNum=7))

Comment: I love PyQT, there is an excellent book on it too http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html

Answer (score 5):

[Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/)